# OpenVPN on a Netgear GS108 switch?

Tags: openvpn, switch

I have a Netgear GS108 gigabit switch - can I flash OpenVPN on this?  My network is as follows

Internet <-> Motorola DSL Modem <-> NetgearGS108 <-> LAN

I'm guessing I can't since this is just a switch and there is no interface??  And I would need a router with an interface to be able to flash OpenVPN on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i very much doubt it. netgear GS108 seems to be cheap, unmanageable switch probably based on quite specialized [realtek](http://www.realtek.com/products/productsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=18&PFid=43&Level=5&Conn=4) or [broadcom](http://broadcom.com/products/Small-Medium-Business/Gigabit-Ethernet-Switching-Products#tab=products-tab) switch-on-the-chip.

imho you are more likely to get openvpn running on your motorola dsl router/modem [ if you manage to [find modified firmware](http://wiki.openwrt.org/oldwiki/openwrtdocs/hardware/motorola/wr850g) for it ] than on your switch.

and obviously you can run openvpn on some box in your lan - on windows as well.. or on linux, and even as virtual machine.